# Using variables in a for loop to assign legend values in pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I've got a DataFrame with several columns including a name, a date and a statistic. I'm plotting a statistic over a period of time to a graph and trying to make the legend of each line match up with the name.

Each time I try something new, I either get the statistic's column name or one name from the name column repeated twice or truncated.

Can I make both names appear in the legend with the existing for loop?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in statistics.groupby('A name'):
    group.plot(ax=ax, label=name)
    print(name)

plt.legend()
```

This code, which prints two separate lines on the plot, gives each line the  the name of the column for the stat I'm plotting instead the name of the person, which is what I'm trying to do with label=name. The print statement in the for loop prints the name correctly.

How can I set the label to each plotted line equal to the correct name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grab those line handles:

```
statistics = pd.DataFrame({'A name':pd.np.random.choice(list('ABCD'),20),'Data Values':np.random.randint(0,100,20)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lh = {}
for name, group in statistics.groupby('A name'):
    lh[name] = group.plot(ax=ax, label=name)
    print(name)

plt.legend(lh)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have enough rep to up vote, but accepted. Thank you! Can you please explain to me how this works? It definitely does but I don't see why it does.

Comment: @vandy... okay I solved that problem. :-) Thank you for accepting!

Comment: @vandy I grab the line handles by creating an empty dictionary and for each loop through, I add a dictionary entry that holds a object which is a line handle. Then I pass that dictionary of line handles to legend to plot.  Legend knows how to get color, line style and label from line handle.  See matplotlib [docs on legend](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)

Comment: Can't tell you how long I spend on legend docs and still couldn't figure this out. I'm still very new so your help and explanation is much appreciated!